# best practice to store mixed type of numbers (percents and flat values)

Tags: php, mysql

I faced a dilemma and very reluctant on which way to go, and if there is a better way to do this.

I have a wildcard input - if you can call it that - which may have these type of inputs

- +0.77
- +0.5%
- -0.51%

The flat values are always positive and the percentage ones can be either.

What is the best practice to store these values? As string or as 2 columns one with value and other for bool for value type?

I'm confused since if I go with the easiest path I face an other problem in some case I need to multiply these said values by an integer and thought about `trim($value, '%')` and then check if it have it to add it in result

Comment: Or you could create two columns: one for the percentage and one for the offset.  Then your formulas could be programmed to take both into consideration simultaneously.  (If I remember this correctly, this is how it was implemented in a pricing system I worked on)

Comment: yeah that was my second approach but i thought 2 columns for one value was overkill but its gonna be more practical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might seems a little bit overkill, but I would definitely go for objects here.

Two classes, one that offset by an absolute value, the other by percentage value. Define a factory method to parse the input string and instantiate either class.

Then, have both classes extends a common interface, which will contains a method like `getAjustedValue(initialValue):ajustedValue`. This will make usage of these ajustment values much easier and cleaner.

**Updated after OP comment**

As for storage in the database, I would store both type of ajustements in distinct columns. It make it very easy to write a SELECT statement that compute the ajusted value, as in:  `SELECT (original_value * ajustement_ratio + ajustement_absolute) as adjusted_value FROM ...`.

Obviously, I expect that ajustements and original_value wouldn't come from the same table, but that give you the big picture.

Comment: i'm more concerned about best practice for storing than managing the values, since the values dont need that much treatment

Comment: Having two distinct columns also has the advantage of allowing you to later support applying both a percentage and an absolute adjustement at the same time, if this is ever wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you just store -0.51% as -0.0051?

Comment: not possible since there is flat values that have -0.0051 as flat values and they need to be differentiated

Comment: You'd still need to know that this is a percentage (expressed as a decimal) for the purpose of applying the modification.